# JFrame not appearing after initialization in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have been working at this for about an hour now attempting to get it working but to no avail.

I am rather new to Java and this is my first time using `JFrame`s but for some reason, when I attempt to initialise this `JFrame` from another `JFrame` it refuses to work.

Step by step:

User inputs a set of integers and clicks calculate

A try-catch catches any `NumberFormatExceptions`

Try-catch then prints error to console and sets the `JFrame` dialogueBox to visible

`JFrame` does not appear

It is worth noting that the dialogueBox

`JFrame` is being called from another `JFrame` called `StudentDetails`.

Code for mouse clicked event listener:

```
    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int score1 = 0;
    int score2 = 0;
    int score3 = 0;
    int score4 = 0;
    int score5 = 0;
    int score6 = 0;
    dialogueBox db = new dialogueBox();
    try {
        score1 = Integer.parseInt(this.testScore1Input.getText());
        score2 = Integer.parseInt(this.TestScore2Input.getText());
        score3 = Integer.parseInt(this.testScore3Input.getText());
        score4 = Integer.parseInt(this.testScore4Input.getText());
        score5 = Integer.parseInt(this.testScore5Input.getText());
        score6 = Integer.parseInt(this.testScore6Input.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
        System.out.println(numberFormatException.toString());
        db.setVisible(true);
    }
    int total = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 + score6);
    float average = total / 6;
    averageScoreOutput.setText(Float.toString(average));

}
```

I was just looking for some insight into why this would not be working and also if anyone has any tips for best practices when using `JFrame`s.

Comment: Your dialog will only show if there is a `NumberFormatException`, which can be circumvented by using a `JSpinner` of `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if anyone has any tips for best practices when using JFrames.

An application should only have a single JFrame. For child/popup windows you should use a `JDialog`.

In your case you should be using a `JOptionPane` which is a customized JDialog.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for examples of using a `JOptionPane`.